# Canonical morphism $\text{im}(f)\to\text{ker}(g)$ for exact sequence in an abelian category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, additive-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. Suppose we have objects $A$, $B$ and $C$, and morphisms $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$ with $g\circ f=0$ i.e. is equal to the zero morphism $A\to C$. In order to make sense of exact sequences in an arbitrary abelian category, it is presumably necessary to have a canonical morphism $\text{im}(f)\to\text{ker}(g)$ making some diagram commutative, but I can't see quite how to pin it down.

There is a morphism $A\to\text{coim}(f)\to\text{im}(f)$, and since $g\circ f=0$, there exists a unique morphism $\alpha:A\to\text{ker}(g)$ with $i\circ\alpha=f$, where $i:\text{ker}(g)\to B$ is the kernel of $g$. But how do I get the right morphism $\text{im}(f)\to\text{ker}(g)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\text{coim}(f):A\to\text{Coim}(f)$ is a cokernel, it must be an epimorphism. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is abelian, the canonical morphism $\text{Coim}(f)\to\text{Im}(f)$ is an isomorphism. Composing these, we get an epimorphism $\alpha:A\to\text{Im}(f)$.

Then since $\alpha$ is an epimorphism, $g\circ\text{im}(f):\text{Im}(f)\to C$ and $0:\text{Im}(f)\to C$ are morphisms with $$(g\circ\text{im}(f))\circ \alpha=0\circ \alpha=0,$$ we have that $g\circ\text{im}(f)=0$. Then the universal property of the kernel $\text{ker}(g):\text{Ker}(g)\to B$ gives that there exists a unique morphism $\theta:\text{Im}(f)\to\text{Ker}(g)$ with $\text{ker}(g)\circ\theta=\text{im}(f)$.

This is the canonical morphism needed to make sense of exactness in abelian categories. We say that $A\to B\to C$ is *exact* at $B$ if this canonical morphism $\text{Im}(f)\to\text{Ker}(g)$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of $g$ is defined as the pullback of $g \colon B \rightarrow C$ and the zero morphism $0 \rightarrow C$. Therefore defining a morphism into this kernel amounts to defining two "compatible" morphisms, namely one into the zero object $0$ (here we have no choice) and one into $B$. Do you see how to get a canonical morphism from $\text{im}(f)$ to $B$?

Comment: Yes, the image is the kernel of the cokernel, and the definition of the kernel includes a morphism from the kernel object to the domain